# mod-rewrite does not set query string variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The heading says everything about my question.

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule ^series/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) series.php?seriesID=$1&season=$2&episodeID=$3
RewriteRule ^series/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+) series.php?seriesID=$1&season=$2
RewriteRule ^series/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) http://my-domain.com/series/$1/1
RewriteRule ^series$ series.php
```

The first RewriteRule does not work. When I call for example `http://my-domain.com/series/my-series/1/1`, the GET variable `episodeID` is not set although I think I defined it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a conflict with `MultiViews`. With MultiViews enabled, mod_negotiation will issue an internal subrequest for `series.php` (appending the file extension to the original request) without a query string *before* mod_rewrite is able to rewrite the URL with the query string parameters.

Try disabling MultiViews at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

You should also remove the two conditions:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> ```

They only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows. But they don't seem to apply to these rules anyway?

> ```
> RewriteRule ^series/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) http://my-domain.com/series/$1/1
> ```

This 3rd rule will also trigger an external 302 redirect. It looks like this should be "similar" to the preceding rule. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^series/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) series.php?seriesID=$1&season=1 [L]
```

AND you should include the `L` flag on each of these `RewriteRule` directives, to prevent the remaining directives being processed.