# I have written an .htaccess RewriteRule and it's not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expression

I want:

http://localhost/electionhope/blog.php?blog_id=3

to function as:

http://localhost/electionhope/blog/3

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)$ blog.php?blog_id=$1 [NC, L]
```

Notice: Undefined index: blog_id in C:\wamp64\www\electionhope\blog.php on line 1

blog.php line #1:

```
<?php $blogID = $_GET['blog_id']; ?>
```

Comment: Use `Options -MultiViews` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: This results in:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at wampserver@wampserver.invalid to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.4.9 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: I changed my httpd.conf to Options All then added Options -Multiviews to the top of the .htaccess file and all is working great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Δce If you changed httpd.conf to `Options All` then you don't strictly need `Options -Multiviews` in `.htaccess` (although it might still be a good idea to include it for when deploying on the live server). `Options All` does not include `MultiViews`, so does not do need to be removed later. (That is of course assuming that you have no other `Options` directive in the server config that is taking priority.) Although this does not explain why you were getting an "Internal Server Error" earlier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mod-rewrite does not set query string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402042/mod-rewrite-does-not-set-query-string-variable)